# Flutterfire won't configure

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to create a firebase project. But when I try to create one using flutterfire, this is what happens:

```
✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · fluttercourse-yung

i New Firebase project fluttercourse-yung created successfully.

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

COMMAND: firebase projects:create fluttercourse-yung --json

ERROR: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Comment: "See firebase-debug.log for more info."
Did you check this file already?

Answer (score 0):

Enter your project name like this

```
my-project-001
```

"-" is important